# tree view table change font awesome color

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a treeview where you click fa-plus-square-o and when it expands fa-minus-square-o shows.

I am using ng-class to show them. What I need to do is change that fa-minus-square-o color to white. However, I do have another page with the same type of treeview. So referencing the fa-minus-square-o directly in the CSS WORKS, but also "changes" the one on the other page. So, I cant do this!!!!. I need it to only affect the current one on that pages treeview.

**HTML Table Treeview**

```
 <table class="users-tree-view-table">
        <tbody class="users-tree-view-tbody">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-class="{selectedUserRole: user === selectedUser}">
            <td class="users-tree-view-column">
                <div class="users-tree-view-row">
                    <span class="fa users-tree-view-toggle" ng-class="{'fa-plus-square-o' : user.isUserCollapsed, 'fa-minus-square-o' : !user.isUserCollapsed}" ng-click="clickedUserNode(user); user.isUserCollapsed = !user.isUserCollapsed"></span>
                    {{user.userName}}
                </div>
                <div uib-collapse="user.isUserCollapsed">
                    <table class="users-tree-view-subtable">
                        <tbody class="users-tree-view-tbody">
                        <tr id="role-{{$index}}"  ng-repeat="role in user.userRoles"  ng-click="setSelectedUserRole(user, role)" ng-class="{true: 'selectedUserRole', false: 'unselectedUserRole'}[user === selectedUser && role === selectedRole]">
                            <td class="users-tree-view-column">
                                <div >
                                    <div class="users-tree-view-row">
                                        <span style="padding-left:45px">{{role}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Hovering over the **fa-minus-square-o** I see I need to reference **fa users-tree-view-toggle fa-minus-square-o** somehow in the CSS?

How can I reference that one particular font awesome without affecting all the other font awesome on other pages?

Comment: do you have any section level or page level identifier? Then you can use that in css

Comment: This is a partial page in another page. its nested deep TBH

Comment: Can i add one to a empty div?

Comment: try `fa.users-tree-view-toggle.fa-minus-square-o{color:white}`

Comment: i got it.  .fa.users-tree-view-toggle.fa-minus-square-o{color:white !important} I had to add a .infront of fa